# Change the width of the span and this span move

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning html and have a question:
I have `<div class="input-group">` which contains: 1 span, 1 input and 1 span:

`<span class="input-group-addon questionSpan" data-toggle="collapse"></span>
 <input class="form-control" type="text">
 <span class="input-group-addon questionSpan" data-toggle="collapse"></span>` 
[image]

and I would like to set the width of these two spans to be equal, in this case this is 42px. But if I do so, then the span on the right will jump to the left.
[image]  Could anyone explain me why this happens and how can I set the width of the span on the right while keeping it not jumping

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18907/)

Comment: I don't see an issue here. Can you explain bit more clearly or with some screenshot.

Comment: If you remove the class questionSpan on the second span, you will see the difference

Comment: Your Fiddle is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the input-group a width of 100%: `width: 100%;`

see [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18914/)